# Updating window relating to terminal size

Tags: python, python-3.x, ncurses, curses, python-curses

I am trying to create a console program that uses curses, in order to have a nice display. For this, I created two windows that represent half the terminal.

For this I have

```
def display(self):
    size_y,size_x = self.stdscr.getmaxyx()
    window_stat = curses.newwin(size_y,size_x//2-5,0,0)
    window_alert = curses.newwin(size_y,size_x//2-5,0,size_x//2+5)
    window_alert.border()
    window_stat.border()
    window_alert.addstr(self.alert2string())
    window_stat.addstr(self.stat2string())
    self.stdscr.refresh()
    window_stat.refresh()
    window_alert.refresh()`
```

I do have two problems anyway. First of all, when I am using `.border()`, the strings are not in the good places. Does border change anything with the content of the window ?

Here is how they are :

```
No data has been collected in the last 10 seconds.────┐          No alert.─────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
│                                                     │          │                                                     │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘          └─────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I want them to be in the box. I guess I can just add like `"\n   "` before them, but is it possible for this to be more clean ?

And, a problem that looks more complicated : `display()` is called every 10 seconds, but if I resize the terminal, `self.stdscr.getmaxyx()` stays the same anyway. Is there a way to understand that the terminal has a different size than before ?

Thanks a lot,
Djaz

Comment: Are you calling `curses.resize_term(size_y,size_x)`?

Comment: No, I am talking about a manual resize from the user of the terminal (putting it in full screen or something). Sorry for the imprecision.

Comment: Could you describe how the strings are not in good places?

Comment: I just updated the main post, so you can have more informations ! Thank you again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before or after you call `display()`, try using the `ch = self.stdscr.getchar()`, which also refreshes the windows, then check for the resize using `ch == curses.KEY_RESIZE` (`ch == 410` should also work). After the check, call `getmaxyx()` and your values should be updated.

I need to know more about what your strings look like in order to solve your placement issue, but you could try moving the y and x positions down (i.e `y-2`) and see if it improves.

Edit: For the string placement, you can use the `move` function on your window to position your cursor. After you intialize the window, call `window_stat.move(size_y+2,size_x+2)` (you can adjust the `2` until you find the right fit). Then do the same thing on your second window.

Comment: Hello, and thank you very much for this idea, I didn't saw it while going through the documentation. The fact is that `getch()` does pause the program right ? It does not continue until it has an input. I would like to continue the program running (if there is no resize, the line will just got updated).

For the window, I just edit my main post, thanks a lot again.

Comment: If you set `stdscr.nodelay(1)`, the `getch()` function with be non-blocking.